# Python- How do I compare a key's value in an IF statement in a FOR loop on a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, for-loop, key

I've shortened it for the purposes of this question, but the code looks like this:

```
total1=0
total2=0
total3=0
score1=20
score2=30
score3=40


players = [{'user': 'Player1', 'total': total1, 'score': score1},
{'user': 'Player2', 'total': total2, 'score': score2},
{'user': 'Player3', 'total': total3, 'score': score3}]

for i in players:
    if players[i]['score'] <= 30:
        ***code goes here***
```

I get this TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

How do I say "If the value of each players score is <= 30"?

If I just write `print players[0]['score']` I get 20. If I write `print players[1]['score']` I get 30, but why can't I put it in a for loop and have "i" be the number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always remember this: in Python "for" is actually "foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first ["for" iterates](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) over the list 'players', so each element is the dictionary:

```
for player in players:
    if player['score'] <= 30:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the list, each `i` is an element of the list, so replace `players[i]` with `i`.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for i in players:
    if players[i]['score'] <= 30:
        ***code goes here***
```

`i` is a the dictionary returned from the list, not the index into the list. What it looks like you want is:

```
for i, player in enumerate(players):
    if player['score'] <= 30:
        ***code goes here***
```

Or even:

```
for player in players:
    if player['score'] <= 30:
        ***code goes here***
```

if you don't need the index later